# Clyther-how to get started?

Tags: python, python-3.x, gpu

I don't get what Clyther is or how to use it.

My stuff:
  ATI OpenCl SDK (just dl'd)
  clyther beta (just dl'd)
  windows 7 pro 64 bit
  active python 3.1.2
  Xfxs Ati radeon 5850 video card

I downloaded the ATI OpenCl SDK and the clyther beta from sourceforge. Then I tooke the sample 'reduce' function from the sourceforge documents and pasted the code into notepad and named it clythersample.py.  When I double-click the file or open it in the interactiveshell, it gives an error message on the first line.

Is naming the file .py wrong? I guess clyther is its own lqnguage and not really python? Can I write python code and in the middle of the program, write a chunk of clyther code? Will python IDEs (esp. Wing understand and debug it?) Will it work with python 3 or do I need 2.6?  Is 64 bit os ok?

(I'm not a programme or technically competent, so things like its a python API for OpenCl or it had C bindings for python don't mean a whole lot).

Answer (score 2):

Clyther is a Python package for High-Performance Computing (HPC) using, for example, video cards with multiple Graphics Packaging Units (GPUs) or (less frequently) multi-core processors.  Clyther is for parallel processing of algorithms or data sets that would normally take a lot of time to process serially.  Meaning, if you have a problem that can be split into many smaller problems, then Clyther is a useful package to use.  Additionally, your problem must be something that can use numpy arrays.

Clyther is a nice package to use if you have the problem it is intended to solve.  It makes it fairly easy to write Python code to run on multiple processes.

If that's not the problem you need to solve, then Clyther probably won't help you.

Answer (score 1):

When you name the file `.py` (the file extension associated with `python.exe`) and double-click it, *how is windows supposed to know it's supposed to run the file with CLyther*?

> Is naming the file .py wrong? I guess clyther is its own lqnguage and not really python?

Documentation compares it with Cython - so I suppose it's an extension to the language, i.e. they take Python and bolt more features on it.

> Can I write python code and in the middle of the program, write a chunk of clyther code?

From the goals of the project, it should (like Cython) ultimately be able to accept all or most Python code. So, yes - but of course you'd have to run the whole program with CLyther.

> Will python IDEs (esp. Wing understand and debug it?)

Not natively, I suppose.

Side note: The project is in a very early stage of developement (very first beta-release), so don't expect things to run smoothly right now.

Comment: How would Windows know it's clyther? 
Well, the clyther code has "@clyther."something in the first line, so I put the clyther code in a python file and I figured python would tell windows what to do. If I don't put the clyther code in a python file, then (a) what is the correct file extension and (b) how would clyther integrate into a python program (I guess you makr python execute a clyther file and pass whatever the output is back to the python program?)

Comment: Windows only cares about the file extension. Even UNIX only cares about the contents if the first line starts with `#!`. And Python, especially releases from before the CLyther release, doesn't even know about CLyther. I don't know the correct file extension (the preferred way would be using the command line). As for last question: At least Cython doesn't, it implements most of Python *and* its extensions itself.